# Android Studio: "run at startup" missing permission

Tags: android, android-manifest

I just published my app in the Google Playstore and it has "run at startup" feature turned on, but I don't have any permission for it in my AndroidManifest. Why is this happening? How could I remove it?

My AndroidManifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
```

Comment: It could be that one of your included libraries needs this permission so it's included by them. Check your libraries and how they work.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the move from `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.4.0` to `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.5.0`